# How do I add stocks of a product in Dolibarr

Tags: erp, dolibarr

Lets say I have a product A.

```
 CASE A
```

This product is manufactured internally. Lets say I manufactured 10 units. How do I add that to stock? Per documentation what I got looks like I have to select the product and go to "Stock" tab, and use the option "Correct Stock". Is this the right way to add stocks of products which are manufactured internally?

```
 CASE B
```

Lets say I  buy Product from another company and stock and resell. How do I add stock in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For manufacturing there is a manufacturing module that solves the problem
https://www.dolistore.com/en/products-services-or-stock/386-Factory--computer-assisted-manufacturing--CAPM-CAMM--for-Dolibarr.html

If you do not want to use it, you can create a module that performs this process, but Dolibarr does not have this feature in its core yet.

Greetings